# Python binascii.crc32 seems not working properly

Tags: python, crc32

I am trying to `CRC16/32` checksum with `binascii.crc32`, `binacsii.crc_hqx`

This is the values I used as an example(I got this example values from 
some network protocol specification I am reading).

1. CRC 16

   input(as ASCII string):123456789

   seed:0x0000

   hash result:0x31c3
2. CRC 32

   input(as ASCII string):123456789

   seed:0x00000000

   hash result:0xd202d277

Below is my test code with above test values.

```
>>> import binascii
>>> hex(binascii.crc_hqx("123456789", 0x0000))
'0x31c3'   #corret result, same as test value result

>>> hex(binascii.crc32("123456789", 0x00000000) & 0xFFFFFFFF)
'0xcbf43926L'#Wrong result, different value from test value result, It Must be 0xd202d277
```

What is a problem...?

Actually I found this sentence in Python doc `Since the algorithm is designed for use as a checksum algorithm, it is not suitable for use as a general hash algorithm.`

Does it mean I can't use it for CRC32 checksum?

If so, Is there any recommendation?

----------------------Edit----------------------

I didn't make the test values myself.

I Just got the values from a document explaining CRC32.

Below is the table I referenced

[image]

----------------------Edit----------------------

In the document containing the figure table, It describes G2S_crc like below.

```
The CRC-32 polynomial defined for G2S can be described as follows:
x32 + x26 + x23 + x22 + x16 + x12 + x11 + x10 + x8 + x7 + x5 + x4 + x2 + x + 1
It is also represented as 0x04C11DB7. This polynomial is also used by IEEE 802.3.
```

.

```
function crc(bit array bitString[1..len], int polynomial)
{
shiftRegister := initial value // either the seed or all 1 bits
for i from 1 to len
{
if most significant bit of shiftRegister = 1
{
// Shift left, place data bit as LSB, then divide
shiftRegister := shiftRegister left shift 1
shiftRegister := shiftRegister or bitString[i]
shiftRegister := shiftRegister xor polynomial
}
else
{
// shiftRegister is not divisible by polynomial yet.
// Just shift left and bring current data bit onto LSB of shiftRegister
shiftRegister := shiftRegister left shift 1
shiftRegister := shiftRegister or bitString[i]
}
}
return shiftRegister
}
```

Is it different from `binascii`?

Comment: no that means it is designed to be a checksum, not a general hashing algorithm ... ergo you should only use it as a checksum ... why do you think that is the wrong result?

Comment: @Joran Beasley By my test values, I think It must be `0xd202d277` not `0xcbf43926`

Comment: why do you think that 0xd292d277 is the correct answer and not 0xcbf42926

Comment: Since they have prefixed the name with "G2S_", I'd expect that G2S_CRC32 != CRC32.

Comment: Do they publish the algorithm they use for G2S_CRC32?

Comment: Note that `hex(binascii.crc32("123456789", 0x00000000) & 0xffffffff)` gives `'0xcbf43926'`,  `hex(binascii.crc32("123456789", 0xffffffff) & 0xffffffff)` gives `'0xd202d277'`, and `hex(binascii.crc32("ABCDEFGH", 0xffffffff) & 0xffffffff)` gives `'0xf201968a'`.  Does the table have the seeds `0x00000000` and `0xffffffff` reversed?

Answer (score 4):

This online calculator

http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html

agrees with Python

[image]

Can you quote the source you got `0xd202d277` from? There are variations regarding bit order etc.

Comment: I thought about posting this ... but decided it didnt really answer the question +1 however for the suggestion that his "source" is either wrong or using a different algorithm ...

Answer (score 2):

From this [CRC catalog](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/17plus.htm#crc.cat.crc-32-mpeg-2), you seem to be using **CRC-32/MPEG-2**. Whereas python uses plain CRC32, with polynom `0xEDB88320`.

BTW, the CRC returned by python is an `int`. And python's int are *signed*. If you need the unsigned representation, you need to [invert the result](https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/11/16/441), like `hex(~0x76e943d9 & 0xffffffff)`.